# Create a text files from the output of find command and send the text file to a remote server using SFTP

Tags: find, sftp, tee

I have a find command that gives the list of files that are older than 5 days, i can tee it into a text file.

`find . -type f -mtime +5 -ls | tee $dir/new.txt`

Now i want to send this text file to a remote server into a dir. How do i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what i wanted using this:

```
find  . -type f -mtime +5 -ls | ssh remoteuser@remoteserver "cat >> $dir/new1.txt"
```